# Toss a die until SIX appears. E (number of ONEs | at leat one TWO) =?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, expectation, dice

A fair die is tossed repeatedly until a Six appears. Let $X$ denote the number of One's
that are thrown in this game/experiment. Let $A$ denote the event that at least one Two was thrown. Compute$ E(X | A)$.

This questions puzzles me because the number of tosses itself is a random variable. I was trying to use $E(X) = E(X|A)Pr(A) + E(X|A^C)Pr(A^C) $. This is how I compute $Pr(A^C)$:

$Pr(A^C) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty Pr(A^C|N=k) Pr(N=K) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (1-\frac{2}{6})^{k-1}(\frac{5}{6})^{k-1}(\frac{1}{6}) = \frac{3}{8}$. However, my notes says $Pr(A^C) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{6} (1 - \frac{2}{6})^{k-1}=\frac{1}{2} $. Where did I (or less likely, the TA) get it wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I think the $E(X) = E(X|Q) P(A) + … $ is a good approach. What didn't seem to work out? Is $P(A^c)$ hard to find?

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes, actually I was trying $Pr(A^C) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} Pr(A^C|N=k) Pr(N=k)$, and the final answer I got was $\frac{1}{16}$, but TA actually got $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @CalvinLin The worse part is I didn't even know how to deal with the $E(X|A^C)$.

Comment: $E(X|A^c) = 5$. Given that you only roll the numbers 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, the probability of rolling a 6 is $\frac{1}{5}$, hence the expected number of rolls is 5.

Comment: @CalvinLin I went through my note again and seems like $\frac{1}{5}$ is not the right answer. But thanks for your comment, I feel like I might know how to proceed now. I'll try again!

Comment: It is somehow 'obvious' that $P(A^c)=\frac{1}{2}$. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this answer is more than you ask for. Maybe you can use it to check your own answer.

Let $N$ denote the number of tosses before the first Six appears.
We will find $\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid A\right)$ on base of:

$$\mathbb{E}X=\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid A\right)P\left(A\right)+\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid A^{c}\right)P\left(A^{c}\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid A\right)\left(1-P\left(A^{c}\right)\right)+\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid A^{c}\right)P\left(A^{c}\right)$$

If we manage to calculate $\mathbb{E}X$, $P\left(A^{c}\right)$ and
$\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid A^{c}\right)$ then we are actually ready.

$N$ takes values in $\left\{ 0,1,2,\dots\right\} $ with $P\left[N=n\right]=\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n}\frac{1}{6}$.
If $B$ denotes the event that the first toss gives a Six then
$\mathbb{E}N=\mathbb{E}\left(N\mid B\right)P(B)+\mathbb{E}\left(N\mid B^{c}\right)P(B^{c})=0\times\frac{1}{6}+\left(1+\mathbb{E}N\right)\times\frac{5}{6}$
leading to $\mathbb{E}N=5$.

Looking at $X$ under condition $N=n$ we deal clearly with a binomial
distribution having parameters $n$ and $\frac{1}{5}$ so $\mathbb{E}X=\mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid N\right)\right)=\mathbb{E}\frac{1}{5}N=1$.

Looking at $\left(X\mid A^{c}\right)$ under condition $N=n$ again
we deal with a binomial distribution, this time with parameters $n$
and $\frac{1}{4}$ wich likewise leads to $\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid A\right)=\frac{5}{4}$. We can calculate $P\left(A^{c}\right)$ by:

$$P\left(A^{c}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P\left(A^{c}\mid N=n\right)P\left(N=n\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{n}\times\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n}\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{2}$$

**However, there is a simpler route. Realize that $A^c$ stands for the event that  'the Six appears before the Two appears'. Off course it has the same probability as its complement $A$: 'the Two appears before the Six appears'.**

So $P(A)=P(A^c)$ and $P(A)+P(A^c)=1$ leading to $P(A^c)=\frac{1}{2}$. Easy isn't it? :-)

Based on $1=\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid A\right)\times\frac{1}{2}+\frac{5}{4}\times\frac{1}{2}$
we find:

> $$\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid A\right)=\frac{3}{4}$$